# How can I find a specific value inside a nested array?

Tags: javascript

Question: I have this array that have a nested array that I want to loop to find a specific value.

```js
arr = [['123456','234567'], ['345678']];
specificValue = '123456';
```

The output that I want is to find out if there's a value same with specificvalue and return this value?

I tried

```js
arr.filter(id => id === specificValue);
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try combining `includes` with the `filter` you're currently using.

Comment: Using Lodash's [flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flattenDeep): `_.flattenDeep(arr).find(specificValue)`.

Comment: Try flat array `arr.flat().filter(id => id === specificValue);`

Comment: `arr` is an array. The elements in `arr` are arrays. Have a look at the other methods of `Array` (but it would also already work with just `.filter()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's keep going with your attempt.

The problem is your array is nested so `array.filter` will not work

Use  `array.flat` with `array.filter`:

```js
let arr = [['123456','234567'], ['345678']];
let specificValue = '123456';
console.log(arr.flat().filter(i=>i==specificValue))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```js
const arr = [['123456','234567'], ['345678']];
const result = arr.flat(Infinity).find(val => val === "123456");
console.log(result);
```

You can learn more about **array.flat()** method here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 1):

Since flat() takes a depth as an argument, to be able to search in an indefinite number of nested arrays you could try good old recursion:

```
const findRecursive = (array, target) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === target) {
      return array[i];
    } else if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      return findRecursive(array[i], target);
    }
  }
}

console.log(findRecursive(arr, specificValue));
```

EDIT: Abdelrhman Mohamed has corrected me, you *can* specify an indefinite amount of nested arrays using `array.flat(Infinity)`